# How come the asterisk outputs at the first line?

Tags: c#

```
    public string PrintRandomShape(int length, int width)
    {
        string output = "";
        for (int rows = 1; rows <= length; rows++)
        {
            if (rows == 1)
            {
                for (int cols = 1; cols <= width; cols++)
                    output += "0";
            }
            else
            {
                for (int cols = 1; cols <= width / 2; cols++)
                    output += " ";

                output += "*";
                output += "\n";
            }
        }
            return output;

//expected output is
000000   *
   *
   *
   *
```

for some reason the asterisk is over there

Comment: What arguments do you pass? What is the `length` and `width` in your method call?

Comment: What do you mean with "over there"? What was your input and unexpected result?

Comment: Guess you want to print a rectangle?

Comment: ... for rectangle print you have to look at the last line, too

Comment: probably because you didn't add the break line in your first output (I am assume the first else where `rows == 1` shouldn't have the star? Btw, new String('0', length) would replace your for-loops ;) An example you could find [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oa9vGO)

Comment: Use PadLeft/PadRight insted of for loop e.g. "*".PadLeft('0', width). It is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you do in your else clause is to add a star, but you never give it a new line, the easiest solution is to add your new line after the loop inside the if clause

```
for (int cols = 1; cols <= width; cols++)
    output += "0";
output += "\n";
```

Comment: @Icepickle - There are a lot of ways you could make this code better.. I'm just trying to keep my answer to the question so it is less confusing to the OP.

Comment: True, I just wanted to offer the framework option for what he likes to do (though this could be a homework thingie to learn for loops offcourse)

Comment: @Icepickle - Feel free to add your own answer :) (Just make sure it still answers the question too!)

Answer (score 1):

Though it could be this is an assigment to learn to work with for loops, there are a few other ways you could use to create this structure with only 1 for loop, nl:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( CreateRandomShape(10, 5) );
    }

    public static string CreateRandomShape(int width, int height) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            if (y == 0) {
                output.AppendLine(new String('0', width));
            } else {
                output.AppendLine(new String(' ', width / 2) + "*");
            }
        }
        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here the repeating of the values is handled by the string constructor, taking a char and the nr of times it needs to repeat the char given. The StringBuilder adds a new line for every output (by using Environment.NewLine (similar to `\n` character, but OS specific) and the output.ToString() then outputs the string content

And as [Sayse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39952834/3231537) mentioned, you get the star in your current solution on the first line, simply because you didn't append a line break. You could handle that in your solution by extracting it like this

```
public string PrintRandomShape(int length, int width)
{
    string output = "";
    for (int rows = 1; rows <= length; rows++)
    {
        if (rows == 1)
        {
            for (int cols = 1; cols <= width; cols++)
                output += "0";
        }
        else
        {
            for (int cols = 1; cols <= width / 2; cols++)
                output += " ";
            output += "*";
        }
        output += "\n"; // this will always append the new line, in both cases...
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the missing NewLine in for loop

```
for (int rows = 1; rows <= length; rows++)
        {
            if (rows == 1)
            {
                for (int cols = 1; cols <= width; cols++)
                    output += "0";
                output += "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                for (int cols = 1; cols <= width / 2; cols++)
                    output += " ";

                output += "*";
                output += "\n";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding complex constructions if you actually don't want them (it's you who have to debug them). In your particular task all you have to do is to print out

- Top line
- Body lines (`length` - 2 times)
- Bottom line

Just do it, and, please, do not cram these implementations into a *single* loop:

```
public string PrintRandomShape(int length, int width) {
  // For public methods validate its arguments 
  if (length <= 0) 
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length");
  else if (width <= 0) 
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("width");

  // When creating a string (esp. in a loop) use StringBuilder
  // length * width + 2 * length - optimization; but it's not that required
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length * width + 2 * length);

  // Top Line: width '0''s
  sb.Append('0', width);

  // Body, try avoiding complex loops with conditions
  // length - 2 (-2 : top + bottom lines == 2) lines of
  // '*' + [width - 2] spaces + '*' strings
  for (int i = 0; i < length - 2; ++i) {
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.Append('*');

    if (width >= 2) {
      sb.Append(' ', width - 2);
      sb.Append('*');
    }
  }

  // Bottom Line width '0''s from new line if total width is greater than 2
  if (length >= 2) {
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.Append('0', width);
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The \n has caused this due to it being a special character. It's put an enter where you don't want one. If you remove it the program should work. Please let me know :)